# Sys.dm_os_performance_counters DMV row counts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, dmv, cardinality-estimates

We have noticed an odd issue on two servers in a 3 node SQL Server 2017 cluster running Always On Availability Groups.

When checking the DMV `sys.dm_os_performance_counters` the row counts are totally out showing 4billion+ rows. It's just a single instance, a very heavy utilised server but only the one.

It does seem to correct itself after a reboot.

This can cause bad plans if we join this DMV with others. The original code was from *SQLWatch* and it was running a *union all* against the DMV which caused a large mem grant. It was also joining the data to internal *SQLWatch* tables. We got around the issue by dumping the dmv data into a temp table and querying that instead.

Has anyone else experienced this?

The code I am running is:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
```

[image: execution plan properties]

[image: estimated execution plan]

Comment: Sounds like something worth reaching directly out to Microsoft about.

Comment: Hi John, yes that's a next stop.
We rebooted the server and the estimates reverted back, which we have seen before. We are going to log the info a table just to track and see if there is an event that happens before the estimates go out of synch